# Load Testing AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-testing, aws-api-gateway, stress-testing

As the question suggests, I need to perform Load Test on the API Gateway Resources with 1 million RPS. Apache JMeter is a very good tool for Load Testing. But I think it won't be possible to simulate such a huge load from a single machine. In that case, JMeter Clusters could be useful. But setting it up could be cumbersome.

I would like to know what are the other solutions can be used?

Does AWS provides any solution? (Code Pipeline has Action to run Load Test, but that will not serve the purpose I guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS doesn't provide load testing solution per se, however it integrates with several load testing providers so you can add a Load Test step into your pipeline and it will kick off a load test from AWS partner side:

- [Automated Performance Testing with AWS CodePipeline](https://loadimpact.com/integrations/performance-testing-aws-codepipeline)
- [A Walk-Through on Performance Testing on the AWS Blog](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/walk-through-performance-testing-aws-blog)
- [Performance Testing in Continuous Delivery Using AWS CodePipeline and BlazeMeter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/performance-testing-in-continuous-delivery-using-aws-codepipeline-and-blazemeter/)

Comment: Hello Dmitri, thank you for the answer, as I mentioned in the original question, how CodePipeline would be helpful on testing API Gateway? Do you mean Piping Lambda code and launch Load Test on API Gateway which is going to hit the deployed Lambda?

Answer (score 4):

You can use BlazeMeter for that - that's exactly what we do.
One thing: Note that JMeter is nor about RPS, but rather about VUs (virtual users).

Comment: We succeeded in AWS API Gateway load testing using JMeter + throughput sharing timer + right config for Concurrency Thread Group so I would say JMeter can be used for testing RPS user cases.

Answer (score 0):

AWS also provide serverless option to test you API as well:

"https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-serverless-to-load-test-amazon-api-gateway-with-authorization/"
[Using serverless to load test Amazon API Gateway with authorization](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-serverless-to-load-test-amazon-api-gateway-with-authorization/)